# Cannot use scipy.stats

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy

I get an errr when using scipy.stats. in a script after  importing scipy.

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'stats'
```

Within script editor I can click on stats after typing scipy. from the pulldown menu,
within python console I can not select python.stats from the pulldown menu, it's not there.
I'm using pandas 2.7 and SciPy 0.13.0
Why is that?
Any known issues?

Comment: Did you import stats, i.e. `from scipy import stats` or `import scipy.stats`. stats subpackage is not imported with `import scipy`, but your editor might do it for tab completion.

Comment: "script editor"? "pulldown menu"?  What editor are you using?  How did you install it?  How did you install python?  In a terminal, does `python -c "import scipy.stats"` give an error?  Also, show the code that generates the error, and the code that imports scipy.stats.

Comment: Thanks, using import scipy.stats worked.

Answer (score 65):

expanding on my comment (to have a listed answer).

Scipy, as many other large packages, doesn't import all modules automatically. If we want to use  the subpackages of scipy, then we need to import them directly.

However, some scipy subpackages load other scipy subpackages, so for example importing scipy.stats also imports a large number of the other packages. But I never rely on this to have the subpackage available in the namespace.

In many packages that use scipy, the preferred pattern is to import the subpackages to have them available by their names, for example:

```
>>> from scipy import stats, optimize, interpolate


>>> import scipy
>>> scipy.stats
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'stats'
>>> scipy.optimize
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'optimize'

>>> import scipy.stats
>>> scipy.optimize
<module 'scipy.optimize' from 'C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\__init__.pyc'>
```

Comment: Maybe mention the explicit guideline for importing from scipy: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/api.html (This shows up often enough, and it's indeed good to have a 'canonic' answer here on SO.)

Comment: Thanks, this explains the observed behaviour. Using import.scipy.stats worked out.

Answer (score 3):

This is expected. Most of the subpackages are not imported when you just do import scipy. There are a lot of them, with a lot of heavy extension modules that take time to load. You should always explicitly import the subpackages that you want to use.

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/13618

Answer (score 1):

if you import scipy alone like this:

```
import scipy
```

then you use:

```
scipy.stats
```

You will get:

```
AttributeError: module 'scipy' has no attribute 'stats'
```

You have to import like this:

```
import scipy.stats
```

or

```
import scipy
import stats
```