# Binomial distribution CDF using scipy.stats.binom.cdf

Tags: python, plot, scipy, histogram, cdf

I wrote below code to use binomial distribution CDF (by using scipy.stats.binom.cdf) to estimate the probability of having NO MORE THAN k heads out of 100 tosses, where k = 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100. 
and then I tried to plot it using `hist()`.

```
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def binomcdf():
    p = 0.5
    n = 100
    x = 0
    for a in range(10):
        print(scipy.stats.binom.cdf(x, n, p))
        x += 10

plt.hist(binomcdf())
plt.show()
```

but I don't know why my plot returns empty, and I receive below error, can anyone help please!

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would save x and the corresponding cdf output for each associated x to a list, then return that list. Then use the data in the list to make plot.

Comment: can you please edit your question and add your logic in piece of code, cause I am very new to python, so I will need code wise advice please

Comment: something like `mylist = []`

Answer (score 3):

You printed your values, but did not return them.  The default return value is `None`, which produced your error.

Comment: What should I return ? cause even when I added return in the end of my function I get the same error!

Comment: @Hazmat: What do you want to plot with `hist()`?  You should return that.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to return calculated values...so you returning None
Should work like this- see below- if I got your intent right :)

```
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def binomcdf():
    p = 0.5
    n = 100
    x = 0
    result = []
    for a in range(10):
        result.append(scipy.stats.binom.cdf(x, n, p))
        x += 10
    return result

plt.hist(binomcdf())
plt.show()
```

Comment: For posterity (or next time I read this answer): Modern scipy wants import scipy.stats not just import scipy. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108017/cannot-use-scipy-stats#22118676

Answer (score 0):

To plot a binomial distribution for every k, you need to store each cdf in an list and return the same list and the same can be used to plot the histogram.