# How to make a binomial CDF in python?

Tags: python

How can i add n choose k and add it to the binomial CDF so i can plot it for my data x?

```
#Parameters: 
n = 2*n+1
p= sum(x)/(2*n+1)

#Binomial CDF

sum((p^i)*(1-p)**(n-i))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to check this link : [Binomial distribution CDF using scipy.stats.binom.cdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46678622/binomial-distribution-cdf-using-scipy-stats-binom-cdf/46678708#46678708)
to plot binomial CDF using matplotlib histogram and scipy stat binom

Answer (score 0):

You can get nCk from :

```
from math import factorial
def n_choose_k(n, k):
    return factorial(n) // factorial(k) // factorial(n-k)
```

Its not super clear however what your goal is, in particular the `n=2*n+1` bit.

Comment: Binomial parameters (2n+1, p=sum(x)/(2n+1))