# scipy.stats is lost when I import my module

Tags: python, scipy, conda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

The problem appears only when I run the code via the Linux command line, i.e. the Windows Subsystem for Linux. It does not occur when run via a conda environment on Windows. In both cases, `scipy` is properly installed.

I have created a function to perform linear regressions of values in rows from across two dataframes `df_1` and `df_2`. Their column names are the same as the keys as the dictionary `data_dict`.

```py
from scipy.stats import linregress
import numpy as np

def foo(df_1, df_2, data_dict):
    for index, row in df_2.iterrows():
        x = []
        for d in data_dict:
            x.append(row[d])
        x = np.array(x)
    for index, row in df_1.iterrows():
        y = []
        for d in data_dict:
            y.append(row[d])
        y = np.array(y)
        s, i, r, p, se = linregress(x, y)
```

This works fine as long as I run it from within the script it is written in, however as soon as I import it into a different script, 'bar' and try to run it I get the error `AttributeError: module 'scipy' has no attribute 'stats'`, and the traceback refers to the line in which `linregress` is actually used, not the import line.

I have tried importing in other ways, i.e.

```py
from scipy import stats
```

As well as importing directly before the linregress operation, i.e.

```py
from scipy.stats import linregress
s, i, r, p, se = linregress(x, y)
```

And finally I've tried seeing if any of the other modules imported to 'bar' are interfering with  `scipy.stats`, and this is not the case.

Any idea why python is 'forgetting' `scipy.stats`?

I also tried checking that `scipy.stats` was imported by writing a list of all modules imported in 'bar' before calling foo;

```py
with open('modules_on_import.txt', 'a') as f:
    for s in sys.modules:
        f.write(f"{s}\n")
f.close()
```

and scipy.stats can be found in modules_on_import.txt

Some more details:

1. I'm not running in virtual environment, `echo $VIRTUAL_ENV` returns nothing.
2. Everything is run via the command line, i.e. directly in Bash. In this case I simply type `python3 bar.py`.
3. All modules installed using pip, via command line - i.e. `pip install scipy`
4. Unsure if it matters, but I'm editing in `vim`.

A (simplified) example of `bar.py`.

```py
from psd_processing import process_psd # function to make df_2 and data_dict
from uptake_processing import process_uptake # function to make df_1
from foo_test import foo

project = '0020'
loading_df = process_uptake(project, 'co2', 298) # this works
param_df, data_dict = process_psd(project, 'n2', 'V') # this works
correlation_df = foo(loading_df, param_df, data_dict) # this breaks on linregress in foo.py
```

It's not the installation method of `scipy`. I uninstalled and reinstalled with `pip3` to be sure.

However, when I run the code via the Spyder IDE, it works!
Some pertinent information;

1. I was originally running the code via Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on Windows 10 x86_64. My Python installation is in `/usr` on Ubuntu.
2. When running in Spyder, the code is run directly on Windows. The python installation is in `C:\Users\<user>\Anaconda3`.

How do I get this code to run properly via the command line?

Comment: One way to get the error `AttributeError: module 'scipy' has no attribute 'stats'` is to import scipy as just `import scipy`, and then attempt to use `scipy.stats.linregress`.  The `stats` submodule must be explicitly imported (e.g. `import scipy.stats` and use `scipy.stats.linregress`, or `from scipy import stats` and use `stats.linregress`), or individual objects must be explicitly imported (e.g. `from scipy.stats import linregress` and use `linregress`).  It sounds like you tried several variations.  Are you sure the example that you show is the one that produced that error?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser yes, I've tried importing foo into a new script, written exactly as you see here. wrt to the import method, that's [the first thing i found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108017/cannot-use-scipy-stats), but I've always been importing linregress specifically.

Comment: Are you using anaconda or venv to create a virtual environment? It sounds like you are running the two different scripts with different python environments. Please explain how you set up the environment, installed packages, and run the two scripts. It will help if you show an actual run (i.e. copy/paste directly from where you run the code) rather than just try to explain in words.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I am running everything in bash, i.e. ```python3 foo.py```. I also printed ```sys.executable``` and ```sys.prefix``` in both foo and bar, and get the same answer from both scripts ```/usr/bin/python3``` and ```/usr```. Will add more information to original post.

Comment: Depending on your Python installation, `pip` may install modules on a Python 2.x installation, while `pip3` installs modules in a Python 3.x installation, so `pip install scipy` might not do what you expect.

Comment: @jjramsey I've updated the question to reflect this, but the scipy installation doesn't appear to be the problem. It appears to be something to do with WSL.

Comment: Is one of your scripts actually named `scipy.py`?

Comment: @tripleee no, none of the scripts I've made are named ```scipy.py```. I do have a script named ```scipy_testing.py```.

Comment: Can you print the value of `scipy.__file__` just before the crash and report back? Does it load the correct library?

Comment: @tripleee I tried adding ```print(scipy.__file__)``` before function ```foo``` is called, as well as within ```foo```, directly before calling ```linregress```. In both cases I get ```NameError: name 'scipy' is not defined```. Also, just to check, I also tried both with ```print(scipy.__file__())```. I did also find a workaround, will supply in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the question, this code works on a conda venv in windows but not in python3 directly installed on the Ubuntu WSL. As my preference is to use the linux command line I did the following workaround;

1. [Install Anaconda on the Ubuntu WSL](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-anaconda-ubuntu-18-04-or-20-04).
2. Create and activate a virtual environment.
3. Install required packages in virtual environment via `conda install <pkg>`.
4. Run everything in the new virtual environment.

Comment: This was actually not the solution. New question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70248438/module-breaks-when-loaded-into-multiple-scripts).