# Module breaks when loaded into multiple scripts

Tags: python, scipy

This is an extension of a question that I thought I solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70204166/scipy-stats-is-lost-when-i-import-my-module/70212557#70212557).

I have two scripts, module_A and module_B. module_A imports [pyGAPS](https://github.com/pauliacomi/pyGAPS). Their imports look like this;

**module_A**

```py
import pygaps # this module uses scipy
def func(args):
...
```

**module_B**

```py
from scipy.stats import linregress
... # generate x and y
def func(args):
    s, i, r, p, se = linregress(x, y)
```

I want to import and use these two modules into a third module, module_C.

**module_C**

```py
from module_A import func
from module_B import func
...
```

When each of these modules are imported and used on their own, module_C works fine. When they are imported as above, I get `AttributeError: module 'scipy' has no attribute 'stats'` from module_B.

I think that `import pygaps` in module_A may be importing an earlier version of scipy, thus when I import it again later it breaks. What's the best way of testing this and avoiding this conflict? This does not occur for any modules which are imported both by `pygaps` as well as my scripts. I have attempted the following already.

One

1. in **module_C**

```py
import sys
from module_A import func
if 'scipy.stats' in sys.modules:
    del sys.modules['scipy.stats']
from module_B import func
```

which throws `AttributeError: module 'scipy' has no attribute 'stats'`

2. in **module_B**

```py
import sys
import importlib
if 'scipy.stats' in sys.modules:
    import importlib
    impotlib.reload(scipy.stats)
else: 
    from scipy.stats import linregress

... # generate x and y
def func(args):
    s, i, r, p, se = linregress(x, y)
```

which throws `NameError: name 'scipy' is not defined`

3. in **module_B**

Don't import `scipy.stats`

Unsurprsingly this throws `NameError: name 'linregress' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with the module imports used in pyPGAPS. The solution was to use the development branch of pyGAPS, and revert to python 3.8.